# Difference between Branch & Bound shortest path variations

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have to implement the following algorithms:

- Branch & Bound
- Branch & Bound w/ Extended list
- Branch & Bound w/ Admissible Heuristic
- A* Algorithm (also referred to as the Dijkstra Algorithm by the later-mentioned MIT guide)

Following [this](http://web.mit.edu/6.034/wwwbob/search-notes-f10.pdf) MIT guide, I was able to form the following understanding of the four implementations.

---

Assuming you're trying to find the shortest (optimal) path between node *S* and node *E*.

---

**Simple Branch & Bound**:

- Has to find the shortest path to each node, before being certain that it found the shortest path to *E*.
- Uses a regular queue to keep track of the nodes which it has to scan.

**Branch & Bound w/ Extended List**

- The extended list keeps track of the nodes that we already visited, so that we do not re-visit nodes that already have optimal paths.
- In order for this method to guarantee an optimal path, a priority queue must be used, so that when we visit a node, we could be sure that the path to that node is optimal (this is not explicitly stated in the guide)
- This algorithm can be stopped once we reach the end-node
- It's better than the regular B&B, but it has no bias towards the end-node *E*, and, therefore, could be faster

**A* algorithm**

`A* = B&B + dynamic programming + admissible heuristic` (from the guide)

- The admissible heuristic *h(N)*, in this case is the length of the currently best-known path to N + the Euclidean distance from N to E.

  - This allows the algorithm to be end-node biased, instead of scanning everything.
- A priority queue is used to pick the next-best node (dynamic programming) (similar to the extended list implementation)

**Branch & Bound w/ admissible heuristic**

Now this is what I have trouble with, since it seems that adding a heuristic without a priority queue is not going to provide any advantage over a simple B&B algorithm because we do not prioritize nodes with a priority queue (because if we did, it would just be the A* algorithm).

Unless, *maybe*, the heuristic allows us to check fewer nodes even without a priority queue through a process that I do not quite understand.

---

It would be great to see an explanation to why we would ever want to add a heuristic to a B&B algorithm without adding a priority queue.

Comment: I'm confused by this question because I don't know when I've ever seen a branching strategy for branch and bound that didn't carve the solution space into disjoint pieces. Also, A* and Dijkstra are different (though related) algorithms; A* with an admissible heuristic is equivalent to Dijkstra on a graph reweighted by that same heuristic (in the degenerate case, if the heuristic is the constant function zero, then A* decays to Dijkstra).

Comment: Also, we'd never have both a bound and a heuristic, since they do basically the same thing.

Comment: Thats what I thought about Dijkstra... So is there an error in what the assignment is asking for? I'm clueless as to how B&B w/ heuristics is different from A*.